# shell script for hosts on mac not working

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sh

Ive been working on some host files to add local network ips to hosts making it easier for my colleagues to access our internal devices without remember the ips

**Hosts.sh file**

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -Fxq "wiki" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'wiki er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer wiki til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.2.13\twiki\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "taxatilbus-docs" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'taxatilbus-docs er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer taxatilbus-docs til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.2.12\ttaxatilbus-docs\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "docucolor" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'docucolor er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer docucolor til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.7\tdocucolor\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "epson" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'epson er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer epson til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.8\tepson\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "brother" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'brother er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer brother til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.9\tbrother\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "mathias-laptop" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'mathias-laptop er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer mathias-laptop til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.18\tmathias-laptop\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "mathias-desktop" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'mathias-desktop er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer mathias-desktop til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.19\tmathias-desktop\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
if grep -Fxq "unifi" /etc/hosts
then
echo 'unifi er allerede tilføjet'
else
echo 'Tilføjer unifi til hosts'
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "192.168.1.11\tunifi\n" >> /etc/hosts'
echo 'wiki er blevet tilføjet'
fi
```

I inform them to put the hosts.sh file at desktop and then go to terminal and write

```
cd Desktop
./hosts.sh
```

but then it just says that the command was not found, and pasting the entire script into the terminal adds the wiki to the host file, but not the rest

Comment: maybe you're missing execution permissions on your script ?

Comment: Could it be the missing shebang?

Comment: BTW, that script is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would recommend some simplification, except what I really recommend is setting up a DNS server and not editing hosts files like this at all.

Comment: Oh, and you keep adding the same line.

Comment: @Biffen should i then just add #!/bin/sh ?
About the DRY, ive written a C# script to compile them both for mac and windows(windows is working as a charm with the bat file). We dont have a server we could use as DNS server sadly.

Comment: @Biffen good you got your eyes open to spot the error adding the same line all the times lol better fix that one

Comment: @Mathias Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Biffen thanks i'll get my colleague to test the new script with the added shebang on monday. they've have already gone for the weekend now

Comment: @funkyjelly they're accounts are the only accounts on the mac, shouldnt they got the access already then? Im not really used to do anything with macs